# How SpringBoot returns errorResponse in JSON format?

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, httpresponse

I am newbie in implementing SpringBoot+RestfulWebservice.In my project, exceptions are handled globally using @ControllerAdvice and Custom class is created to set the error code and error message in String format.We are passing the error object to HTTPResponse and returing the response.But I am wondering how the errormessages are converted in JSON format as , we are not explicitly using any httpMessageConverter.

```
- Is Spring Boot internally do the conversion?
```

Please help me in understanding the behavior. Give me some insights,though you feel like its basic question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Spring Boot defaults to JSON for all the things when you don't provide specifics around content-type negotiation.

As per the spring boot documentation on error handling [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) using `@ControllerAdvice` defaults to producing JSON formatted errors. From the docs:

> You can also define a class annotated with @ControllerAdvice to customize the JSON document to return for a particular controller and/or exception type, as shown in the following example:

[This page](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-rest-error-handling-example/) on mkyong.com has a good write up about how to customise the ControllerAdvice error handling.

As an example of JSON usage, this very bare bones controller will do its best to render any POJO as JSON (note if you just provide a primitive like a `long` it will simply return the primitive in text, but set the content-type as `application/json`)

```
@RequestMapping("api/time")
@RestController
public class TestApi {

    @GetMapping
    public Map<String, Long> time(){
        Map<String, Long> res = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        res.put("time_in_nanos", System.nanoTime());
        return res;
    }
}
```

example:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/time
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/time HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2020 04:18:35 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"time_in_nanos":47078744054692}
```

That's for default requests (ie no `Accept` header, or `Accept: */*`), if you specify `application/xml` or something else it typically wont work:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/api/time --header 'Accept: application/xml'
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /api/time HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: application/xml
>
< HTTP/1.1 406
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Tue, 04 Feb 2020 04:17:38 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 0):

By default springboot registers the following `HttpMessageConverters` on startup :

```
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter – converts byte arrays
StringHttpMessageConverter – converts Strings
ResourceHttpMessageConverter – converts org.springframework.core.io.Resource for any type of octet stream
SourceHttpMessageConverter – converts javax.xml.transform.Source
FormHttpMessageConverter – converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap<String, String>.
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter – converts Java objects to/from XML (added only if JAXB2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson 2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson is present on the classpath)
AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter – converts Atom feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
RssChannelHttpMessageConverter – converts RSS feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
```

So, if you are returning an object from your controller advice , spring will automatically by default call the Jackson converter to convert the object into a valid Json response.

Basically springboot checks the `MIME` type to decide which implementation of `HttpMessageConverter` to use.Also, it will depend on the "Accept" header to decide the type of data that the caller is expecting.If it's a request thatis received springboot will use the "Content-type" header to decide the type of data that is send.

Comment: Thank you, Anantha for the clarification.

Comment: @satyanehru Happy to be of help.

Comment: @satyanehru Happy to be of help.